# How should I write an XPath to extract the contents what I need？

Tags: python, web-scraping, web-crawler

I want to extract the contents of all the H3 tags and P tags under Div[class="main_bottom_left_content"].How should I write an XPath?
I would appreciate it if you could solve my problem.

[image]

Comment: Please include your current attempt

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `.//div[@class="main_bottom_left_content" and @id="pj_content"]`

Comment: Thank you for your reply.Can you tell me how to write loop expressions to extract these tags of h3 and p？